# ETIMEDOUT on graphql requests

Tags: graphql, timeout

I'm using craft's graphql to generate a static site with a nuxt frontend. The generator manages to generate about 40 routes, then it returns

`Error: Network error: request to https://geo-api.heimatschutz.ch/api failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT`

and it doesn't generate the rest of the routes. Is there some configuration within craft that limits how many requests the api can receive? My php max_execution_time is already 30 seconds, I don't think that's the problem. but maybe there are other PHP variables I haven't thought about.

Thanks for any suggestions.